# Taking a long time setting up views

Tags: android

I have a form with about 100 views and apparently all the findViewById is taking a long long time. And i need to do a save and retrieving of the form fields which takes around 2-3 seconds freezing the UI thread.

Is there any way to make it look better? I read that its not feasible to call findViewById or any UI related stuff on another thread but i have no choice.

Saving the forms from that many field is taking alot of time as well.. im doing it on another thread currently.

On honeycomb 3.1. please help. many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to rethink your design, perhaps you could use a ListView, which'll only construct enough views to fill the screen, rather than the entire UI. You could also use the events from the edit controls to update a structure with the current values as they are edited rather than waiting til the end then trying to read all the values in one go.

Comment: I am using list views where needed. I have a list of questions with rows of 3 radiobuttons dynamically generated. apparently the views are about 3-4 pages on a view flipper so i can switch them around. i am initializing them at one go. thats why its taking so long..

Comment: I think the problem which superfell is telling you to avoid, is not initializing all the views in one go. That's the usage of AdapterViews such as ListView. It will try to efficiently precreate views that are coming up and recycle views that have already been created, to reduce the time spent in creating new views and reduce the memory cost of having so many views in memory.